# Is there a good way to detect empty results in a Linq-To-Entities query?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

The only way I know of is awkward:

```
'check for empty return
Dim count As Integer = (From s In myEntity.employee Where employeeID = myEmployeeIDVariable).Count

'If there is a record, then process
If count > 0 Then
     Dim r = (From s In myEntity.employee Where employeeID = myEmployeeIDVariable).First()

     . . . do stuff . . .
End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign LINQ result to a variable and check if .Count() is > 0. That way you will not need to do the same query twice.

Code:

```
'check for empty return
Dim r = (From s In myEntity.employee Where employeeID = myEmployeeIDVariable)

'If there is a record, then process
If r.Count() > 0 Then
  . . . do stuff . . .
End If
```

Comment: Thanks.  The "count" method doesn't exist in a "first" call. But, I tried removing "first" and then inside the if statement created a new variable that is just the "first" result. "dim rr = r.first()" Looks a lot better and keeps the query in one place.

Comment: Just be aware, if you call .Count() and .First() on the same query, it may result in two hits to the database (Linq-to-Objects would evaluate the query twice, but I don't know about Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-SQL).

Comment: Ah yes, that would be my error when copying and pasting your original code.

Answer (score 6):

Use .FirstOrDefault().  You'll get the first record if there is one, or null if there isn't a record returned.

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen that in some examples, but never tried it out.  Appreciate the tip.